# SQL, query records with opposite signs

Tags: sql, match

I have a view with the following fields:

```
Key, ID, Value.
```

Some pairs of records (not necessarily sequential) have the following property:

```
Key1, ID1, Value1
Key2, ID1, -Value1.
```

How can I write a query to return all such records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Self-joins are your friend:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id, t1.key, t1.value, t2.key, t2.value
FROM   my_table t1
JOIN   my_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.value = -1 * t2.value
```